# How can I decode a large data QR code image?

Tags: windows-mobile, decode, qr-code

I've created an application that scans QR code images in window 7 mobile applications, but my problem is that the content type-like URL is decoded successfully, but information about the person or large text does not decode and it will cause a render exception.

My code is the following:

```
    private void ScanPreviewBuffer()
    {
        try
        {
            _photoCamera.GetPreviewBufferY(_luminance.PreviewBufferY);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(_luminance);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            var result = _reader.decode(binBitmap);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => DisplayResult(result.Text));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();

        }
    }


    public class PhotoCameraLuminanceSource : LuminanceSource
    {
        public byte[] PreviewBufferY { get; private set; }

        public PhotoCameraLuminanceSource(int width, int height)
            : base(width, height)
        {
            PreviewBufferY = new byte[width * height];
        }

        public override sbyte[] Matrix
        {
            get { return (sbyte[])(Array)PreviewBufferY; }
        }

        public override sbyte[] getRow(int y, sbyte[] row)
        {
            if (row == null || row.Length < Width)
            {
                row = new sbyte[Width];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                row[i] = (sbyte)PreviewBufferY[i * Width + y];

            return row;
        }
```

This code causes render exceptions when decoding a qr code image with large amounts of data. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Do you have an example QR you can share with us?